# How to add fold-marks to a Google Docs document?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

This question is about how to get fold-marks (very similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/374458/how-to-print-fold-marks-on-letters-using-microsoft-word)) to your document in Google Docs. It would be very helpful. If it is not feasible per se are there any workarounds?

Comment: This (very interesting) question would be much better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/